# How to set a default date and time to PrimeNG p-calendar

Tags: angular, angular5, primeng, angular-bootstrap-calendar

I have included `p-calendar` in my project with `showTime="true"` :

```
  <p-calendar formControlName="pre_check_in" [defaultDate]="defaultDate"  [minDate]="dateTime" showTime="true" hourFormat="24" showButtonBar="true"    required>
```

Then in my TS file i have used `setValue` to assign data fetched from database to the respected formControlls:

```
 private passService(qsUserId) {
    this._appService.getEditVisitData(qsUserId).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      this.editCheckinData = data;

      this.editCheckinForm.controls[ 'id' ].setValue(this.editCheckinData[ 'id' ]);
      this.editCheckinForm.controls[ 'f_name' ].setValue(this.editCheckinData[ 'f_name' ]);
      this.editCheckinForm.controls[ 'l_name' ].setValue(this.editCheckinData[ 'l_name' ]);
      this.editCheckinForm.controls[ 'purpose' ].setValue(this.editCheckinData[ 'purpose' ]);
      this.editCheckinForm.controls[ 'department' ].setValue(this.editCheckinData[ 'department' ]);
       this.editCheckinForm.controls[ 'pre_check_in' ].setValue(this.editCheckinData[ 'pre_check_in' ]);
     // this.date1 = this.editCheckinData[ 'pre_check_in' ];
    });

  }
```

Other fields show the desired data but the `p-calendar` still remains empty. Is it possible to show the data in the `p-calendar` as default date. 
The data that is been fetched to display in the form is in the following format:

```
check_in:null
checkin_status:false
created_at:"2018-04-12T04:56:43.000Z"
creator_email:"atul.vurung@gmail.com"
creator_id:"atul.vurung@gmail.com"
creator_mobileno:0
department:"D0001"
entry_source:"admin"
f_name:"erd"
id:43
l_name:"erd"
organization:"ORG_VURUNG"
pre_check_in:"2018-04-12T04:56:20.744Z"
purpose:"discuss"
updated_at:"2018-04-12T04:56:43.000Z"
visitor_type:"visitor"
```

Comment: what do you get  for this.editCheckinData[ 'pre_check_in' ] when console.log it

Comment: @SuvethanNantha when i console log that i get `2018-04-12T04:56:20.744Z`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
const formattedDate=new Date(this.editCheckinData[ 'pre_check_in']);
this.editCheckinForm.controls[ 'pre_check_in' ].setValue(formattedDate);
```

I hope this will work for you. If you have any issues let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help, This will only works if you want to show the date in calendar.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this might help you.

In your TS File
eg. `this.defaultDate = new Date();`

In your HTML file
eg. `<p-calendar formControlName="pre_check_in" [defaultDate]="defaultDate"  [minDate]="dateTime" showTime="true" hourFormat="24" showButtonBar="true"   required>`

Comment: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=176751#p176751

I can able to solve this mindate , maxdate issue in primeng calendar.
I had to add localvariable and updateCalendarUI;
Also I had to set minDate and MaxDate with following logic:
updateCalendarUI(calendar: Calendar) {
this.maxDate = new Date(); this.maxDate.setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 65); this.maxDate.setMonth(new Date().getMonth()); this.minDate.setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() - 10); this.minDate.setMonth(new Date().getMonth()); calendar.updateUI(); }

Answer (score 0):

According to Docs: [PrimeNg Calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v13/calendar)  we can set the value using two way binding as shown in the example:

> HTML File

```html
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="defaultDate"></p-calendar>
```

> TS File

```html
export class MyModel {

    defaultDate: Date;
    // or new Date() if you want to set today's date

}
```

And done!